# How to swap text back and forth when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text

What I need is to swap back and forth the text `____` (a gap) to `Word` by clicking it. I don't want to have a button. The user should only need to click at the position of the gap.

I see [this page](https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/) describes exactly what I need, especially the CSS-Only Way, but when I try it on the TryIt Editor, either it or the jQuery-Way doesn't work.

Here is the CSS Way:

```
</style>
#example {
 position: relative; 
} 
#example-checkbox {
 display: none;
} 
#example-checkbox:checked + #example:after {
 content: "Hide";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: white;
 }
</style>

<input id="example-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="example" id="example">Show</label>
```

Comment: Where is text _""____""_ at `html` at Question?

Comment: oh, the given code is copied from the link. It should be replaced to `Show`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that will meet your requirement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  This is a paragraph. Click on the next word -&gt; <span id="word" onclick="toggle()">____</span> &lt;- Have you clicked on previous word.

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function toggle() {
      var word = document.getElementById("word").innerHTML;
      if (word.split('_').join('').trim().length === 0) {
        document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = "word";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = "_____";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

## Having multiple hidden words

In the code below, just take a look at script in `<head>` section of the code.

```
  <script>
    var words = [];

    words.push('vocabulary');
    words.push('lexicon');
  </script>
```

**Here, you just have to push the words that you want to toggle with `_____` in the array `words`. Once the words are pushed in this array, they will automatically convert, back and forth to underscores. Just push any different word in this array from the paragraph and see the transitions yourself.**

```css
span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var words = [];

    words.push('vocabulary');
    words.push('lexicon');
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <p id="demo">A vocabulary is a list of words that an individual knows or uses regularly. vocabulary is different from lexicon because vocabulary is about what an individual or group of people know, whereas lexicon is about the language itself.
  </p>

  <script>
    function toggle(element) {
      if (element.innerHTML.split('_').join('').trim().length === 0) {
        element.innerHTML = element.getAttribute("word");
      } else {
        element.innerHTML = "_______";
      }
    }

    $.each(words, function(index, value) {
      var replacestr = new RegExp(value, "g");
      $("p#demo:contains('" + value + "')").html(function(_, html) {
        return html.replace(replacestr, ' <span class = "smallcaps" word="' + value + '" onclick="toggle(this)"> ' + value + ' </span>')
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

## Making `________` appears first when page loads

Just replace

```
return html.replace(replacestr, ' <span class = "smallcaps" word="' + value + '" onclick="toggle(this)"> ' + value + ' </span>')
```

with

```
return html.replace(replacestr, ' <span class = "smallcaps" word="' + value + '" onclick="toggle(this)">____________</span>')
```

**The final code will be:**

```css
span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var words = [];

    words.push('vocabulary');
    words.push('lexicon');
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <p id="demo">A vocabulary is a list of words that an individual knows or uses regularly. vocabulary is different from lexicon because vocabulary is about what an individual or group of people know, whereas lexicon is about the language itself.
  </p>

  <script>
    function toggle(element) {
      if (element.innerHTML.split('_').join('').trim().length === 0) {
        element.innerHTML = element.getAttribute("word");
      } else {
        element.innerHTML = "_______";
      }
    }

    $.each(words, function(index, value) {
      var replacestr = new RegExp(value, "g");
      $("p#demo:contains('" + value + "')").html(function(_, html) {
        return html.replace(replacestr, ' <span class = "smallcaps" word="' + value + '" onclick="toggle(this)">_______</span>')
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

## For both plurals and singulars

Just change the line:

```
var replacestr = new RegExp(value, "g");
```

to:

```
var replacestr = new RegExp('\\b'+value+'\\b', "g");
```

The final code would then look like:

```css
span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var words = [];

    words.push('vocabulary');
    words.push('lexicon');
    words.push('lexicons');
    
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <p id="demo">A vocabulary is a list of words that an individual knows or uses regularly. vocabulary is different from lexicon because vocabulary is about what an individual or group of people know, whereas lexicon is about the language itself. In this paragraph, lexicons is a new word that's added, so don't forget to push 'lexicons' in your array.
  </p>

  <script>
    function toggle(element) {
      if (element.innerHTML.split('_').join('').trim().length === 0) {
        element.innerHTML = element.getAttribute("word");
      } else {
        element.innerHTML = "_______";
      }
    }

    $.each(words, function(index, value) {
      var replacestr = new RegExp('\\b'+value+'\\b', "g");
      $("p#demo:contains('" + value + "')").html(function(_, html) {
        return html.replace(replacestr, ' <span class = "smallcaps" word="' + value + '" onclick="toggle(this)">_______</span>')
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I put this on one site and it works, while another site doesn't. I open a new question for debugging this, hope to see you there. [How to start debugging jQuery if there seems to be no error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69696108/3416774)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you expect?

```
<input id="example-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="example-checkbox" id="example">Show</label>
```

Note the `for` attribute in `label`- it must have the `id` of the `input` checkbox

```css
#example {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#example-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
#example-checkbox:checked + #example:after {
  content: "Hide";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<input id="example-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="example-checkbox" id="example">Show</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Label's `for` attribute must contain the id of the **checkbox**

```css
#example {
  position: relative;
}
#example-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
#example-checkbox:checked + #example:after {
  content: "Hide";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<input id="example-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="example-checkbox" id="example">Show</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<label id="example-five" for="example-five-checkbox">_____</label>
```

Reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/n1rb2y57/
But see to that you choose proper background color in css matching with the website color.