# How to start debugging jQuery if there seems to be no error?

Tags: jquery

I have a script to [swap text back and forth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38806001/3416774):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var words = [];
words.push('vocabulary');
words.push('lexicon');
words.push('lexicons');
</script>

<p id="demo">A vocabulary is a list of words that an individual knows or uses regularly. vocabulary is different from lexicon because vocabulary is about what an individual or group of people know, whereas lexicon is about the language itself. In this paragraph, lexicons is a new word that's added, so don't forget to push 'lexicons' in your array.</p>

<script>
function toggle(element) {
  if (element.innerHTML.split('_').join('').trim().length === 0) {
    element.innerHTML = element.getAttribute("word");
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = "_______";
  }
}

$.each(words, function(index, value) {
  var replacestr = new RegExp('\\b'+value+'\\b', "g");
  $("p#demo:contains('" + value + "')").html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(replacestr, ' <span class = "smallcaps" word="' + value + '" onclick="toggle(this)">_______</span>')
  });
});
</script>
```

In [one site](https://lyminhnhat.com/learn-vocab-from-context?utm_source=SO%20%C2%BB%20swap%20text%20back%20and%20forth&utm_medium=Learn%20vocab%20from%20context&utm_campaign=Get%20help) this works perfectly, but in [another site](https://qu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com/learn-vocab-from-context?utm_source=SO%20%C2%BB%20swap%20text%20back%20and%20forth&utm_medium=Learn%20vocab%20from%20context&utm_campaign=Get%20help) it doesn't. I open the console log in site 2 and it's fluffed with other messages and I don't know how to filter the ones I need. But skimming it I guess there is no actual problem. I open the debugger panel and see that in site 1 the jQuery version is 3.5.1, while in site 2 it's still 2.1.1. I suspect we can start from here, but even then why doesn't the old version work?

The script in site 2 are from line 1188 to line 1213. On site 1 I put the script into a plugin, but on site 2 I just put them together in one place

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't appear to be included on `site 2` so it is never run. On `site 1` I can see the scripts that initiate the toggling...

First is the word array builder which is found in the `<head>` tag.
[image]

Second is the `toggle` function and initiator.
[image]

Both of which do not appear to be included in `site 2`.

---

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, your script is actually included however, your paragraph contains none of the words in your array.

This is your paragraph:
[image]

And this is your words array:
[image]

Your script is searching the above paragraph for: `vocabulary`, `lexicon` and `lexicons` all of which are not in the content.

Comment: The script in site 2 are from [line 1188 to line 1213](https://i.imgur.com/pck9tp7.png). On site 1 I put the script into a plugin, but on site 2 I just put them together in one place

Comment: Ah yes I see. For me the script is actually on line 110 as an encoded source. I assume this is because of some optomisation you have.

Comment: @Ooker I've updated my answer. Tldr: your paragraph doesn't contain any matching words.

Comment: oh men. How careless I am. The answer is in front of me, yet I'm unable to figure out. Thank you so much for your help